# Reduced Homology the same under Homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am currently doing Hatcher's problem 2.1.13:

Verify that $f \simeq g$ implies $f_* = g_*$ for induced homomorphisms of reduced homology groups.

By inspected of the regular and reduced chains, it is evident that $H_n(X) = \tilde{H}_n(X)$ for $n > 0$, so all that is left to prove is the case $n = 0$. Since $H_0(X) = \frac{\ker \partial_0}{\text{im } \partial _1}$ and $\tilde{H}_0(X) = \frac{\ker \epsilon}{\text{im } \partial_1}$, is it enough to show that $\ker\epsilon \cong \ker \partial_0$ to prove the statement? If so, how would you go about starting it?

Comment: This is not true. Typically $\tilde H_0(X)$ is smaller than $H_0(X)$. What you should show instead is how to define a chain homotopy between $f_\sharp$ and $g_\sharp$.

Comment: @RyleeLyman So I understand that the prism operator $P$ is a chain homotopy between $f_\#$ and $g_\#$, but was unsure where to move from there. That is why I tried this different approach.

Comment: The question not not really a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3054869, but the core of that question is identical with the present question.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I agree. However I will mark it closed because RyleeLyman showed me my original thought was not correct and to follow the one present in the link. Thanks.